# Applying Custom CSS to Crystal Reports in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

How do I apply CSS to crystal reports in my webpage, so that it stays in the div that I wish to appear in and do not float out of that div.
I also want to disable the toggle tree group, how do i achieve this.
If possible please provide a sample example.
As I am new to this, please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to use your custom CSS in the page where you use the Crystal Report and try to use !important after style to override the default CSS style and check the styling in firebug